# Repository pattern in Entity framework where clause

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to get all users for specific role. I have write below query. But it gives me converstion error.

```
List<Expression<Func<AspNetUsers, object>>> include = new List<Expression<Func<AspNetUsers, object>>>();
Expression<Func<AspNetUsers, object>> roleInclude = (roles) => roles.AspNetRoles;
include.Add(roleInclude);
string roleName="Admin";
var users = Repository<AspNetUsers>.GetEntityListForQuery(r=>r.AspNetRoles.Where(y=>y.Name == roleName),null,include);
```

How to write these where clause?

In syntax itself it gives below error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable {AspNetUser} to bool

How to write where clause for another entity?

Comment: You said `it gives me converstion error`, what is the exact error message? Can you [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31308188/edit) and add the exact error message?

Comment: The expression your looking for should be `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<AspNetUsers, bool>>`